# Unable to click on submenu item in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, submenu

Unable to click on sub menu item in Google forms. 
I could able to inspect element only till File->New

It has a sub menu which is like File->Menu->Document. Screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB5ne.jpg). I couldn't find the element locator for document and mouse over is not working.

```
WebElement newfile = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[14]/div[4]/div"));
newfile.click();

WebElement newfile = driver.findElement(By.linkText("New"));
```

HTML:

```
<div id="docs-file-menu" role="menuitem" class="menu-button goog-control goog-inline-block" aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">File</div>
<div class="goog-menuitem-content" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><span aria-label="New, n;" class="goog-menuitem-label" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><span class="goog-menuitem-mnemonic-hint" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">N</span>ew</span><span class="goog-submenu-arrow" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">►</span></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the `html`?

Comment: <div id="docs-file-menu" role="menuitem" class="menu-button goog-control goog-inline-block" aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">File</div><div class="goog-menuitem-content" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><span aria-label="New, n;" class="goog-menuitem-label" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><span class="goog-menuitem-mnemonic-hint" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">N</span>ew</span><span class="goog-submenu-arrow" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">►</span></div>

Comment: @anup: [Edit] into the question, please.

Comment: [link](http://www.google.com/forms/about/)--> Go to Google forms-->logged in with user credentials ->clicked on File->New->Document..<div class="goog-menuitem-content" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><span aria-label="New, n;" class="goog-menuitem-label" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><span class="goog-menuitem-mnemonic-hint" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">N</span>ew</span><span class="goog-submenu-arrow" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">►</span></div>

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be the most efficient way of writing all this, give this a try. It works for me:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://docs.google.com/forms/create?usp=mkt_forms")

email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='Email']")
time.sleep(1) #it would bug without more time to load... sometimes..
email.send_keys('youremail@gmail.com')
time.sleep(1) #time for email to be entered

password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='Passwd']")
password.send_keys('yourpassword')
time.sleep(1) #time for password to be entered

submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='signIn']")
submit.click()

time.sleep(2) #give time for Google forms to load
menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='docs-file-menu']")
ActionChains(driver).click(menu).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform()

#rejoice
```

Also, its in Python. If you're using Java, it should be easy to switch over.

Comment: A small explanation what @anup was doing wrong or what went wrong might have been useful for future searchers...